# Send a javascript array to server using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to send this array:

```
results = [1, 4, 5, 6]
```

So, I'm using this call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'save_record',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ sheets: results }),
        dataType: "json",
        success : function (data) {
            // Code here
        }
    });
```

But my PHP file is not receiving any parameter :(   What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'save_record',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {sheets:JSON.stringify(results)},
        dataType: "json",
        success : function (data) {
            // Code here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'save_record',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        sheets: results 
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success : function (data) {
        // Code here
    }
});
```

Comment: This just sends a "Array" value to server :(